# How can I force re-authentication with the Windows Live OAuth API?

Tags: oauth, hotmail, windows-live

Is there a parameter I can pass to https://oauth.live.com/authorize that will force the user to login again?

The problem is if the user is logged in, it will redirect transparently back to my site, even if the user wants to use a different Windows Live account.

Twitter's OAuth API accepts "force_redirect=true", and Facebook accepts "auth_type=reauthenticate", but I can't find one for Windows Live.

Answer (score 2):

First redirect your user to:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf?client_id={$Client_Id}&redirect_uri={$Redirect_URI}
```

It will log him off and then continue your coding !